# py2exe compiled .exe won't start

Tags: python-2.7, py2exe

I compiled my prototype Application with py2exe to check its function as an exe, and run into 0 errors until I go to start it. Nothing happens. A process starts with my app name, it thinks for a few seconds, then nothing. No log file is generated. The app works great when run in python environment, but not in the compiled exe. I've given my setup code below. Any ideas? :

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe, sys, os
import matplotlib
import FileDialog
import dateutil

sys.argv.append('py2exe')

setup( windows=['ATLAS.pyw'], data_files=matplotlib.get_py2exe_datafiles(),
    options = {"py2exe": {
            "includes": "decimal, datetime",
            "packages": ["FileDialog", "dateutil"],
            'bundle_files': 2, 
            'compressed': True}
        },
    zipfile = None
)
```

Hooks utilized in the Application:

```
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2TkAgg
from matplotlib.backend_bases import key_press_handler
from pandas.sandbox.qtpandas import DataFrameWidget
from matplotlib.widgets import LassoSelector
from tkFileDialog import askopenfilename
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore
from matplotlib.path import Path
import pandas.io.sql as psql
from numpy import nonzero
import tkMessageBox as mb
from pylab import *
import pyodbc
import sys
import ttk
```

Comment: Navigate to the executable in a command prompt and run it there.  It shouldn't fix it, but you will be able to see any of the errors it is producing.

Comment: @Sculper There is still nothing. No errors. I'm also having a similar issue using PyInstaller as a compiler. I compile, no issues, but application won't run. Just a quick cmd prompt pop up. Added my hooks in the OP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED:

So, using quick fingers (and compiling it with PyInstaller with the `--debug` option) I screen-capped the quickly-closing console window that contained the Traceback:

`WindowsError: [Error 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'C:\\path\\dateutil\\zoneinfo/*.*'`

The `zoneinfo` file was being saved in pytz instead of dateutil. A quick rename solved the problem.

Only issue though, if you want to compile with `-F` or `--onefile` it will not work due to the initial improper naming convention. Not quite sure how to fix that though.